# No tests discovered when using VSCode, python and absolute imports

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, windows-10, python-unittest

I am trying to add unit tests to my python project and I can't get VS Code to discover my test. The problem is when I try to import the `class` that I am testing.

- If I try to `run` the test file, it passes.
- If I omit the `from A.myfile import MyFile` the test is discovered.

**Question**: What am I doing wrong here?

---

**File structure**:

```
root
├── A
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── myfile.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── A
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_myfile.py
```

**myfile.py**:

```
class MyFile(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 1
```

**test_myfile.py**:

```
import unittest
from A.myfile import MyFile

class Test_MyFile(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_file(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

**.env**:

```
PYTHONPATH=PATH_TO_ROOT
```

**settings.json**:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "PATH_TO_PYTHON\python.exe",
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./tests",
        "-p",
        "test_*.py",
        "-t",
        "."
    ],
    "python.envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

**Python test log**:

```
start
```

VSCode version: 1.38.1
Python version: 2.7.14 (x64)

Comment: Is your root folder added to the path? 
```cd /path/to/root && export PATH=$PATH:$(pwd)```

Comment: Only to the `PYTHONPATH` - thats why I have the `.env` file. I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of the value set for `-t`. If `unittest` is interpreting that `-` to use the default setting then it's using `-s` which is the `tests` directory, and so your `import A` line is importing `tests/A/__init__.py` instead of `A/__init__.py` which is leading to an `ImportError` when `A.myfile` can't be found (check the test output to see the failure).

Change that `-` to `.` and it should hopefully fix things to anchor the top directory for your project.

Comment: You're definitely right on the *dash*, but sadly it doesn't fix the issue. I have fixed the mistake in the question. I have been thinking about this during the evening, and is my problem, that python doesn't look into the `root/A/` folder when it has already found the `root/test/A` folder which is much closer to the test file?

Comment: @Chau I just noticed you're using Python 2 and not Python 3. Add `from __future__ import absolute_imports` and see if that fixes things.

Comment: I have tried that and even with a python 3 environment and still the test is not discovered :|

Comment: @Chau have you tried this in a terminal and had it working? Basically the extension isn't doing anything magical, so you can take those arguments from your config and play with them in the terminal until it works for you ([docs on unittest discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery)). Otherwise I would just rename your `tests/A` directory to `tests/test_A` to avoid the package name collision or try using pytest to do the discovery (it will still let you use unittest for writing your tests).

Comment: It's completely ridiculous that in 2022, IDEs/extensions are still having trouble with finding unit tests.

Comment: The situation I encountered is that the directory containing the _test.py test file must contain an __init__.py file, even if it is an empty file, in order for the python vscode plugin to scan the test file in this directory